# Story of the devil's deal with a man to have riches and status

Tags: story-identification

I’m looking to remember the story of a man who summoned the devil to have riches fame and status for a certain amount of years, I believe 25. He enjoyed his deal, he even jumped planets, saw kingdoms, and had all the pleasures in the world. When his time came the devil collected his soul and one of servants came and saw his room ripped to shreds with blood on the walls. I’m trying to figure out what story this is from.

Comment: I've edited to clear this up a bit, you had written "servals" and I assume you meant "servants", however, if this isn't correct please [edit] to update. Also can you take a look at [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/58193) and see if there is anything else you can edit into the post? For example, when did you read/see this? Was it a novel, short story, movie, TV episode etc?

Comment: The description is roughly a retelling of Faust, but there have been many adaptions of this story. The thing that most sticks out as unique in your question is the space travel aspect, can you provide any more details on this?

Comment: This story sounds like it is a modern retake on the fairy tale 'Jack-o-lantern', maybe if you look up modern fiction relating to the fairy tale you may find it?

Answer (score 1):

I second that it sounds like Faust, especially Christopher Marlowe's version, Doctor Faustus. An agent of the devil grants him power for 24 years. He experiences great pleasures, visits other kingdoms (even assaulting the Pope), and at the end his servants find him ripped to pieces.

He doesn't leave the planet unless you stretch it to include Hell. Perhaps an adaptation of the play?